# Is there a way of configuring jelly's 'optionalBlock' so that it also removes an entry?

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, jelly

I am making a Jenkins plugin, which scans the workspace of the current project for certain folders and fills a drop-down selection box with what it finds. However, if it doesn't find anything, I want to give the user the option to enter the folder name manually.

In order to make this look neat and simple, I want to use an [optionalBlock](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jelly+form+controls) so the user can tick 'Enter manually' and a text field appears. However, at that point I also want the original drop-down to disappear. How do I do that?

This is what I have at the moment, but of course this doesn't make the drop-down disappear:

```
<f:entry field="folder" title="Choose folder">
 <f:select />
</f:entry>
<f:block>
 <table>
    <f:optionalBlock name="enterManually" title="Enter folder name manually">
        <f:entry title="Folder name">
            <f:textbox name="folderManual"/>
        </f:entry>
    </f:optionalBlock>
 </table>
</f:block>
```

Essentially I want to configure the `optionalBlock` so that it shows one thing when it is not checked, and another when it IS checked.

Does anyone know how to do this or have any suggestions on how I can achieve this in some other way? Maybe I can somehow combine two `optionalBlocks` to configure this?